# Loop to get up-to-date information constantly from another variable in JS/angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-scope

I have an angular app that uses jPlayer as a playlist for mp3s. The call to `$scope.audios[defaultPlaylist.current].id` returns the most up-to-date value of the currently playing audio's key. I need to retrieve this key constantly (or whenever it changes).

Is there some kind of loop I can write that constantly checks the return value of `$scope.audios[defaultPlaylist.current].id` (and then stores the value in `$scope.current_audio_id`)?

```
$scope.current_audio_id = $scope.audios[defaultPlaylist.current].id
```

Answer (score 0):

try it as a function

```
$scope.current_audio_id = function(){
  return $scope.audios[defaultPlaylist.current].id;
}
```

and then calling from HTML as `{{current_audio_id()}}`